# send params from volley android to php with post method

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I want send parameters by volley to php page in host. But I get the following error.

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400
```

This is my php code

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $user = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "select * from users where email = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";

    require_once('config.php');
    $result = mysqli_query($con , $sql);
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if(isset($check)){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failure";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

This is file config.php

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "testDb"

$con = mysqli_connect($serverName , $userName , $password , $dbName) or die("connect failed");
?>
```

and This is my android code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(config.SHARED_PREF_NAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF , false);
        Log.e("txt" , "text is : " + loggedIn);
        if (loggedIn){
            Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this , profileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void login(){

        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, config.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("StartActivity", response.toString());
                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                    //Creating a shared preference
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = loginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    //Adding values to editor
                    editor.putBoolean(config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                    editor.putString(config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);
                    //Saving values to editor
                    editor.commit();

                    //Starting profile activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, profileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    //If the server response is not success
                    //Displaying an error message on toast
                    Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("s" , "invalid sssssssssssssssssssssss");
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
                params.put(config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

And when that runs onResponse else command is executed .
The transmission parameters with post method values ​​are wrong

thankyou

Answer (score 1):

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400

A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules.

> Error Caused by:

You forgot to put semicolon after the `$dbName`, which causes the db to die again and again without showing any `Exception` via Login Link, Correct:

```
$dbName = "testDb"; //<--here forgot to add semicolon
```

> Correction - Try code:

```
@Override
 public Map<String, String> getParams() {
  Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("user", email);     //here
  params.put("pass", password);  //here
  return params;
 }
};
```

> Correction - Require once before interacting with table:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

require_once('config.php'); //here

$sql = "select * from users where email = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";
```

Comment: Okay, now I'm testing

Comment: BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://librarylib.gigfa.com/login.php

Comment: It must be submitted using the method of post parameters to success message is printed

Comment: I think i found the answer, Did any other operations are working on your db ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding `getParams()` try overriding `getBodyContentType()` and `getBody()`.

Something like this :

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, config.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.i("StartActivity", response.toString());
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
            //Creating a shared preference
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = loginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            //Adding values to editor
            editor.putBoolean(config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
            editor.putString(config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);
            //Saving values to editor
            editor.commit();

            //Starting profile activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, profileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            //If the server response is not success
            //Displaying an error message on toast
            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("s" , "invalid sssssssssssssssssssssss");
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
}){
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        final JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
        try {
            body.put(config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
            body.put(config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return body.toString().getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
        return headers;
    }
};
```

Check this question : [StringRequest with JSON body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451094/stringrequest-with-json-body)

Comment: The transmitted data is not the type of json

Comment: @Ali then of what type?

Comment: The transmitted data are of type string

Comment: @Ali Did you try with the above mentioned code? Looking at your params suggests that you shouldn't have any issue with content type being application/json

Comment: I have updated the getBody method to send your params.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.
Do not need to change my php code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134401/discussion-between-abhishek-jain-and-ali).